# Laravel Mix, TailwindCSS, and PurgeCSS

Tags: laravel-mix, tailwind-css, css-purge

First time using laravel mix, I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

I have a project where I'm attempting to use Laravel mix to compile tailwindcss and then use purge to remove any unused css.

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://*******************.git"
  },
  "author": "Sean Smith",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "**************",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.16",
    "laravel-mix-purgecss": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-easy-import": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-nested": "^4.1.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.6.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "laravel-mix-purgecss": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
// copied from https://gist.github.com/Log1x/8c1d63024cad15cfb05eec495c41a75b

const mix = require('laravel-mix')
require('laravel-mix-purgecss')

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Sage application. By default, we are compiling the Sass file
 | for your application, as well as bundling up your JS files.
 |
 */

// Public Path
mix.setPublicPath('./public')

// Browsersync
// mix.browserSync('https://example.test')

/**
 * Custom PurgeCSS Extractor
 * https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss
 * https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss-webpack-plugin
 */
// Styles
mix.postCss('src/css/styles.css', 'public/assets/css', [
  require('postcss-import')(),
  require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.config.js'),
  require('postcss-nested')(), 
  require('postcss-preset-env')(),  
]).purgeCss({
    enabled: mix.inProduction(),
    folders: ['src', 'templates'],
    extensions: ['twig','html','js','php', 'vue'],
    extractorPattern: [/[a-zA-Z0-9-:_/]+/g],
  })

// JavaScript
mix.js('src/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js')
  .extract()

// Source maps when not in production.
if (!mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.sourceMaps()
}

// Hash and version files in production.
if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.version()
}
```

When I run npm run prod everything appears to work correctly. However in the exported styles.css the only styles that are there are from from tailwind/base

styles.css

```
/* tailwind base; */
@import "tailwindcss/base";

/* tailwind components; */
@import "tailwindcss/components";

/* tailwind utilities; */
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

/* all shared css here */
@import "./components/shared.css"
```

None of the classes that are in my templates/index.twig file have been added nor are the styles in ./components/shared.css file.

classes exist in both index.html and shared.css so should **not** be purged

When I **remove purgeCSS** the output css file includes everything as expected. However **when purge is added** in the **only output is tailwind/base css**.

Please advise.

Here's a screenshot of my directory structure

[image]

Comment: I'm also struggling with this Sean, although my issue is that is just can't get PurgeCss to run without an error...

Answer (score 0):

When you use mix.postCss() or a separate postcss.config.js file, Mix overrides all other PostCSS plugins, including the PurgeCSS instance, added by this plugin.

To work around this issue, include your PostCSS plugins with mix.options()

```
  const mix = require('laravel-mix');
  require('laravel-mix-purgecss');

  mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
     .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
     .options({
        postCss: [require('tailwindcss')]
      })
     .purgeCss({
        enabled: mix.inProduction(),
     });
```

Refer https://github.com/spatie/laravel-mix-purgecss for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show us your `tailwind.config.js` file ?
The file should contain something like that :

```
module.exports = {
purge: [
    './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
    './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
],

theme: {
    extend: {
        lineClamp: {
            10 :"10",
            12 : "12"
        },
        fontFamily: {
            sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        },

    },
},

variants: {
    extend: {
        lineClamp : ["hover"],
        opacity: ['disabled'],
    },
},

plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/line-clamp"), require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
};
```

purge array should contain the file that you would like to be purged.

```
purge: [
'./vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
'./storage/framework/views/*.php',
'./resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
],
```

In this exemple above, the command purge will purge the file at the directory `/vendor/laravel/jetstream/` and `**` mean look at all subfolder under jetstream and finaly the `*` mean that all file that have `.blade.php` extension at the jetstream folder and folder should be purged

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."